# How to loop through <li and extract/parse data in between?

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing, find

I have a html source code as a variable and want to loop through each li and extract the required data . I tried using $(strVar).find("li").each(function(){alert($(this).text()); }); but i could not get the data in between!Could you guys show me how this can done.Thanks

```
Data to extract from first li:
-1(li class id)
-https://website.com/image1.jpg (li background image url)
-writing reports(div text with class name:class="task_name")
-for items sold(div text with class name:class="training_text")
-1.mp4(input value with class name: class="video")

Data to extract from second li:
-2(li class id)
-https://website.com/image2.jpg(li background image url)
-drawing(div text with class name class="task_name")
-using oil paint(div text with class name:class="training_text")
-2.mp4(input value with class name: class="video")
```

html code:

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function MyFunction()
{
var strVar="";
strVar += "<li class=\"tasks\" id=\"1\">";
strVar += "";
strVar += "<div style=\"background-image:url(https:\/\/website.com\/image1.jpg);overflow:visible; z-index:2; position:relative;\" class=\"ex_thumbnail\">";
strVar += "      <div class=\"float-right\"><\/div>";
strVar += "      <img class=\"vipicon\" src=\"https:\/\/www.awebsite.com\/vip.svg\"\/>      ";
strVar += "   <\/div>";
strVar += "   <div class=\"task_texts \"";
strVar += "      style=\"\"";
strVar += "      >";
strVar += "      <div class=\"task_name\">writing reports<\/div>";
strVar += "      <div class=\"training_text\">for items sold<\/div>";
strVar += "   <\/div>";
strVar += "   <input type=\"hidden\" class=\"image1\" value=\"11.jpg\"\/>";
strVar += "   <input type=\"hidden\" class=\"tools\" value=\"adobe photshop\"\/>";
strVar += "   <input type=\"hidden\" class=\"video\" value=\"1.mp4\"\/> ";
strVar += "   <input type=\"hidden\" class=\"thumbnail\" value=\"14.jpg\"\/>";
strVar += "";
strVar += "<\/li>";
strVar += "";
strVar += "<li class=\"tasks\" id=\"2\">";
strVar += "";
strVar += "<div style=\"background-image:url(https:\/\/website.com\/image2.jpg);overflow:visible; z-index:2; position:relative;\" class=\"ex_thumbnail\">";
strVar += "      <div class=\"float-right\"><\/div>";
strVar += "      <img class=\"vipicon\" src=\"https:\/\/www.awebsite.com\/vip.svg\"\/>      ";
strVar += "   <\/div>";
strVar += "   <div class=\"task_texts \"";
strVar += "      style=\"\"";
strVar += "      >";
strVar += "      <div class=\"task_name\">drawing<\/div>";
strVar += "      <div class=\"training_text\">using oil paint<\/div>";
strVar += "   <\/div>";
strVar += "   <input type=\"hidden\" class=\"image1\" value=\"12.jpg\"\/>";
strVar += "   <input type=\"hidden\" class=\"tools\" value=\"brush\"\/>";
strVar += "   <input type=\"hidden\" class=\"video\" value=\"2.mp4\"\/> ";
strVar += "   <input type=\"hidden\" class=\"thumbnail\" value=\"15.jpg\"\/>";
strVar += "";
strVar += "<\/li>";

//here I want to loop through each <li and extract the required data and display them in group
}
</script>

</head>

<body>
<br>
<button onclick="MyFunction()">Parse Li</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Where is `myFunction()`? What have you tried?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I edited my first post i tried to use $(strVar).find("li").each(function(){alert($(this).text()); }); but I am not getting data to process further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue with the code you've shown is that you're using `find()`, however the `li` you're trying to retrieve are the root objects in the HTML, so you need to use `filter()` instead.

From there you can use `map()` to build an array of object containing the data you need to retrieve from the `li`:

```
let bgRe = /^url\((['"]?)(.*)\1\)$/
let data = $(strVar).filter("li").map(function() {
  let $li = $(this);
  return {
    id: this.id,
    bgImageUrl: bgRe.exec($li.find('.ex_thumbnail').css('background-image'))[2],
    reports: $li.find('.task_name').text().trim(),
    items: $li.find('.training_text').text().trim(),
    video: $li.find('.video').val()
  }
}).get();
```

```js
function MyFunction() {
  var strVar = "";
  strVar += "<li class=\"tasks\" id=\"1\">";
  strVar += "";
  strVar += "<div style=\"background-image:url(https:\/\/website.com\/image1.jpg);overflow:visible; z-index:2; position:relative;\" class=\"ex_thumbnail\">";
  strVar += "      <div class=\"float-right\"><\/div>";
  strVar += "      <img class=\"vipicon\" src=\"https:\/\/www.awebsite.com\/vip.svg\"\/>      ";
  strVar += "   <\/div>";
  strVar += "   <div class=\"task_texts \"";
  strVar += "      style=\"\"";
  strVar += "      >";
  strVar += "      <div class=\"task_name\">writing reports<\/div>";
  strVar += "      <div class=\"training_text\">for items sold<\/div>";
  strVar += "   <\/div>";
  strVar += "   <input type=\"hidden\" class=\"image1\" value=\"11.jpg\"\/>";
  strVar += "   <input type=\"hidden\" class=\"tools\" value=\"adobe photshop\"\/>";
  strVar += "   <input type=\"hidden\" class=\"video\" value=\"1.mp4\"\/> ";
  strVar += "   <input type=\"hidden\" class=\"thumbnail\" value=\"14.jpg\"\/>";
  strVar += "";
  strVar += "<\/li>";
  strVar += "";
  strVar += "<li class=\"tasks\" id=\"2\">";
  strVar += "";
  strVar += "<div style=\"background-image:url(https:\/\/website.com\/image2.jpg);overflow:visible; z-index:2; position:relative;\" class=\"ex_thumbnail\">";
  strVar += "      <div class=\"float-right\"><\/div>";
  strVar += "      <img class=\"vipicon\" src=\"https:\/\/www.awebsite.com\/vip.svg\"\/>      ";
  strVar += "   <\/div>";
  strVar += "   <div class=\"task_texts \"";
  strVar += "      style=\"\"";
  strVar += "      >";
  strVar += "      <div class=\"task_name\">drawing<\/div>";
  strVar += "      <div class=\"training_text\">using oil paint<\/div>";
  strVar += "   <\/div>";
  strVar += "   <input type=\"hidden\" class=\"image1\" value=\"12.jpg\"\/>";
  strVar += "   <input type=\"hidden\" class=\"tools\" value=\"brush\"\/>";
  strVar += "   <input type=\"hidden\" class=\"video\" value=\"2.mp4\"\/> ";
  strVar += "   <input type=\"hidden\" class=\"thumbnail\" value=\"15.jpg\"\/>";
  strVar += "";
  strVar += "<\/li>";

  let bgRe = /^url\((['"]?)(.*)\1\)$/
  let data = $(strVar).filter("li").map(function() {
    let $li = $(this);
    return {
      id: this.id,
      bgImageUrl: bgRe.exec($li.find('.ex_thumbnail').css('background-image'))[2],
      reports: $li.find('.task_name').text().trim(),
      items: $li.find('.training_text').text().trim(),
      video: $li.find('.video').val()
    }
  }).get();
  
  console.log(data);
}

MyFunction();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Many Many thanks for perfect answer. I am learning alot from it:-)